# Android notification action icon: Resources not found exception

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-resources, android-package-managers

I am currently working on an android app which recreates the notifications from the notification center. To fully recreate the notification experience i also tried making the notification actions available in my app (eg. the back/play/pause/next buttons from music notifications).

```
Icon icon = notification.actions[0].getIcon();
((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.action0)).setImageIcon(icon);
```

But i get a resource not found exception in the second line above.

```
E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x7f020259 from pkg=
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020259
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
[...]
```

I think the problem is that the icon is from a different app and can't be accessed that easy, but i can't figure out how to access the icon correctly.

I know how to access resources from other apps when i have a resource id as int, but in this case i only have an icon but no resource id.

Edit:

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Action.html#getIcon()

Accessing the pending intent from the actions works perfectly

Comment: hi Frecki just update ImageViw initialization method don't use ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.action0)).setImageIcon(icon); but try 
Imageview action0 = (Imageview)view.findViewById(R.id.action0);
action0.setImageIcon(icon);

Comment: @KrunalPatel tried it, didnt solve it :(

Comment: what is your device api level ?

Answer (score 0):

The Notification.Action.Icon.java doesn't store the icon bitmap, it only store its resource ID, your app can't read other app's resource, it searches its own resource and can't find the ID, so throws a exception.

in [Notification.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Notification.java#965)

```
public Icon getIcon() {
    if (mIcon == null && icon != 0) {
        // you snuck an icon in here without using the builder; let's try to keep it
        mIcon = Icon.createWithResource("", icon);
    }
    return mIcon;
}
```

in [Icon.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.java#476)

```
public static Icon createWithResource(String resPackage, @DrawableRes int resId) {
    if (resPackage == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource package name must not be null.");
    }
    final Icon rep = new Icon(TYPE_RESOURCE);
    rep.mInt1 = resId;     
    rep.mString1 = resPackage      
    return rep;
}
```

Comment: So it is not possible to get the icon from the notification?

Comment: With this code:
`int resource = (int)notification.extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
                Context packageContext = context.createPackageContext(notifications.get(position).getPackageName(),0);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(packageContext.getResources(),resource);`
I am able to get the "small icon" which is also from another apps package....is there no way similar to this to get the action-icon?

Comment: According to the source code, it should depend on how the icon create, there are four types, TYPE_BITMAP, TYPE_RESOURCE, TYPE_DATA, TYPE_URI.

Comment: You have got the resource ID, maybe you can also get the bitmap with the method you mention above, and then pass the bitmap to ImageView

Comment: I find getResources() method in Icon.java, maybe you can use it.